# How to reference a SASS function without importing in all angular component SCSS file

Tags: angular, sass

I am trying to implement a approach, 
created a font function for 'rem' in angular SASS file and @import it in styles.scss
will it will be added in all components?
or we need to add in all scss component files, which I think its not the right way to do it, below is my code

```
variable.scss
---------------------
$base-font-size: 16px;

// Write your function here

@function px-to-rem ($target, $context: $base-font-size) {
  @return ($target / $context) * 1rem;
} 


styles.scss
-----------------------
@import 'variable.scss';


expectation  auto import 'variable.scss' in all components
---------------------------

component1.scss 
.example {
 font-size: px-to-rem(12px);
}

component2.scss 
....

component3.scss 
....
```